# Primitive Twitch.tv IRC Chat Bot

Tags: python, security, chat

So currently I have this basic little chat bot that can read commands and can timeout users if their message contains a banned word or phrase. I was wondering how I can improve on this bot to be able to `!add "word"` to the set of banned words and overall general flaw improvements.

```
import string
from Read import getUser, getMessage
from Socket import openSocket, sendMessage
from Initialize import joinRoom

s = openSocket()
joinRoom(s)
readbuffer = ""
banned_set = {"badword1", "badword2"}
while True:
        readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
        temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
        readbuffer = temp.pop()

        for line in temp:
            print(line)
            if "PING" in line:
                s.send(line.replace("PING", "PONG"))
                break
            user = getUser(line)
            message = getMessage(line)
            print user + " typed :" + message
            if not banned_set.isdisjoint(message.lower().split()):
                sendMessage(s, "/timeout " + user)
                break
            if "!guitars" in message:
                sendMessage(s, "Ibanez RG920QM Premium")
                break
```

Comment: Adding features is off-topic for Code Review, so I think your `!add "word"` idea may not be realised here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issues [@zondo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/99934/zondo) [has pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124488/primitive-twitch-tv-irc-chat-bot#124490) (*i.e.* [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), some better operators, and the string features), I would also like to point out a few things.

**1)  Variable names**
Variables names such as `temp` [are to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850123/why-using-a-variable-name-temp-considered-a-bad-practice).  A **much** better name for this variable would be something like `lines`, `messages`, `stack`, `messageStack`<sup>^</sup>, etc.

<sup>**^** Note:  *non PEP 8 camelCasing used to be consistent with existing code as posted.  Obviously you would make this `message_stack` when fixing that issue.*</sup>

---

**2) Don't `PONG` everybody!**
In your code, it should be noted, that lines 17 - 19 inclusive (shown below for brevity) introduce some (probably?) undesired behaviour...

```
        if "PING" in line:
            s.send(line.replace("PING", "PONG"))
            break
```

Consider that a user in the chat *says* "`PING`".  Your bot will replace it with `PONG` and send the message back to the room.

This would be particularly bad given that this if-statement occurs before the *banned words* checking code (and `break`'s out of the loop).  Users can now use bad words to their heart's content, provided they include the word "PING" (in uppercase) in their message!  Furthermore, the *bot* will **repeat** these bad words back to the room!! **(This is how security bugs get created)**

<sub>*Note, if you do end up implementing an `!add` command to insert items into `banned_set`, **PLEASE** ensure you have successfully protected your adding code from [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)!*</sub>

---

**3) Decide your case-consistency and stick with it.**
On line 23 you include a call to `message.lower()` (the result of which is not stored anywhere).  Then on line 26 your compare `message` to a lower-case command string (`"!guitars"`).  Do you want `"!Guitars"` to work just like `"!guitars"`?  If so, you may want to make `message` lowercase before you split it (as you're already doing for the bad-words check).

Furthermore, with your current logic the message "I've just added the !guitars command to my bot" will trigger the **same** response as just saying "!guitars".  This is because your current logic (using the `in` operator,) disregards the *position* of the command string within the message.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that `Read`, `Socket`, and `Initialize` are modules you wrote.  The functions defined in there do not follow PEP 8 naming conventions.  PEP 8 says to use `snake_case`, not `mixedCase`.

Your indentation also does not follow PEP 8.  You should use four-space indentation, not eight-space.  At the very least, you should be consistent.

> ```
> readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
> ```

Re-defining something to be itself plus something else is so common that many languages have the `+=` operator.  You can use it here:

```
readbuffer += s.recv(1024)
```

Python also has `*=`, `/=`, `//=`, `^=`, etc.

> ```
> temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
> ```

There is a better way to split each line:

```
temp = readbuffer.splitlines()
```

Since that line was the only place you used the `string` module, you can remove that import.  You didn't need it anyway, though, because `str` has the `.split()` method.

> ```
> print user + " typed :" + message
> ```

Instead of concatenation, use a format string:

```
print "{0} typed: {1}".format(user, message)
```